how to pass request->user() to QueuedExport in laravel nova excel
In maatwebsite/laravel-nova-excel package, I'm trying to use QueuedExport to generate an excel report.
With DownloadExcel, everything worked fine, but when I switched to QueuedExport,
"Call to a member function funcName() on null" exception happens
->canSee(fn () => $request->user()->funcName()) - code in one of the nova fields
It seems like $request->user() is not properly serialized or passed down to queue, so it just returns null
I tried extending base QueuedExport, manually passing user object to action constructor, but nothing helped
